# nuntio font is not a system

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to load a Font with AppLoading but I get this error: Nunito is not font.
Why I get this error and How can I fix it?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Alert } from 'react-native';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { createStackNavigator, HeaderTitle } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Header from './shared/header';
import Home from './screens/home';
import About from './screens/about';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

...

const getFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    'nunito-regular': require('./assets/fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf'),
    'nunito-bold': require('./assets/fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf')
  })
};


const App = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);
  if(fontsLoaded) {
  return (<NavigationContainer><AppStack /></NavigationContainer>)
  } else {
    return (<AppLoading startAsync={getFonts} onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)} />)
  }
};

export default App;
```

Is use it like this:

```
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'nunito-regular'}}>Hello</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the function `async` as the `Font.loadAsync` is an `async` function so you have to `await` it

It should look like this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Alert } from "react-native";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import { createStackNavigator, HeaderTitle } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Header from "./shared/header";
import Home from "./screens/home";
import About from "./screens/about";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";

const getFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    "nunito-regular": require("./assets/fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf"),
    "nunito-bold": require("./assets/fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf"),
  });
};

const App = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);
  
  if (fontsLoaded) {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AppStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={getFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine.. Check [this](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/testing-fontloadasync) out . I've created a Snack which may help you

Comment: yes I have to delete my node folders and reinstall expo font